# Ejabberd + Docker | Node name mismatch: I'm [ejaberd@...], the database is owned by [ejabberd@...]

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ejabberd

I'm trying to setup ejabberd server via docker so I could use pidgin to chat with my teammates.

I have the following docker compose file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  ejabberd:
    image: rroemhild/ejabberd
    ports:
      - "5222:5222"
      - "5269:5269"
      - "5280:5280"
    environment:
      - ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd
      - XMPP_DOMAIN=localhost
      - EJABBERD_ADMINS=admin
      - EJABBERD_USERS=admin:pass1 user1:pass2 user2:pass3
    volumes:
      - ssl:/opt/ejabberd/ssl
      - backup:/opt/ejabberd/backup
      - upload:/opt/ejabberd/upload
      - database:/opt/ejabberd/database
volumes:
  ssl:
  backup:
  upload:
  database:
```

Whenever I try to launch ejabberd I get this error:

> ejabberd_1  | 05:52:58.912 [critical] Node name mismatch: I'm
>   [ejabberd@986834bd1bc8], the database is owned by
>   [ejabberd@319f85780c99] ejabberd_1  | 05:52:58.912 [critical] Either
>   set ERLANG_NODE in ejabberdctl.cfg or change node name in Mnesia

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I had the same problem. When I started the containers first time round, the node ID got allocated and the DB persisted on one of the named volumes, owned by this node. A subsequent start allocated a different ID but the DB was still being owned by the previous node, hence the name mismatch error. Wiping out the volumes helped (obviously, this wipes the DB too).

Answer (score 0):

Because your hostname is changing when Docker is initialised, you'll need to override the `ERLANG_NODE` setting in /etc/ejabberd/ejabberdctl.cfg. For example:

```
ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@mypermanenthostname
```

If others are attempting to migrating an ejabberd instance, they can do something similar, but the instructions they really want are:

https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/managing/#ad-hoc-commands